# pdf2htmlEX cannot open or read file

Tags: docker, pdf-generation, pdf-to-html, pdf2htmlex

I installed docker and run pdf2htmlEX through it

```
alias pdf2htmlEX="docker run -ti --rm -v ~/pdf:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX"
pdf2htmlEX -h 
pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 test.pdf
```

This is my path and the pdf's contained inside:

```
~/Desktop/pdf$ ls 
test.pdf    testpdf.pdf
```

When running the following commands:

```
df2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 test.pdf
df2htmlEX test.pdf
df2htmlEX pdf/test.pdf
df2htmlEX ~pdf/test.pdf
```

and other combinations with the full path before test.pdf I continue to get unable to read the file errors.

```
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'test.pdf': No such file or directory.
Error: Cannot read the file
```

I am not sure if permissions is a cause, but when checking on user permissions it has read and write:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 test.pdf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 testpdf.pdf
```

Any idea on why it is not finding or cannot read the pdf file that is there?  I am trying to convert it to .html

Comment: With Fedora 28, I had the same issue. The culprit was SELinux.

Answer (score 2):

Host path should be directed like this.

```
docker run -ti --rm -v /Users/<path>:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX test.pdf
```

Please refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 1):

not sure if other people ran into this problem, but the documentation was unclear to me.

```
brew install pdf2htmlex
```

and then restart your terminal did the trick for me.  I am not sure if that was required with docker spinning up pdf2htmlex or not, but it worked for me.